# How to use githooks via ansible

Tags: ansible, githooks

All [Git hooks](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks) are ordinary scripts that Git executes when certain events occur in the repository.

Can I use these client-side hooks, when i update my repository with the [builtin git-module from ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html)?

The following Demo-Playbook creates a repository and a clone in the `/tmp` folder.
The `post-merge`-script adds a line to a file.
The ansible-module ignores this script, but the shell-command `git pull` creates the new line.

```
$ cat git-demo.yml
---
- name: git pull demo
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:

  - name: create directory
    file:
      dest: /tmp/demo
      state: directory

  - name: init repo
    shell: git -C /tmp/demo init

  - name: create first commit
    shell: date >> /tmp/demo/test.txt;git -C /tmp/demo add .;git -C /tmp/demo commit -m1

  - name: clone demo
    ansible.builtin.git:
      repo: /tmp/demo
      dest: /tmp/test

  - name: create hook-script
    copy:
      dest: /tmp/test/.git/hooks/post-merge
      content: |
        #!/bin/sh
        date +"%F %T Demonstrating git-hook" >> /tmp/demo/test.txt
      mode: 0755

  - name: create second commit
    shell: date >> /tmp/demo/test.txt;git -C /tmp/demo commit -am2

  - name: git pull without hook
    ansible.builtin.git:
      repo: /tmp/demo
      dest: /tmp/test

  - name: create third commit
    shell: date >> /tmp/demo/test.txt;git -C /tmp/demo commit -am3

  - name: git pull with hook-script
    shell: git -C /tmp/test pull
```

Only the shell-module invoked the hook-script:

```
$ ansible-playbook git-demo.yml
$ cat /tmp/demo/test.txt
Thu 24 Mar 2022 02:13:06 AM CET
Thu 24 Mar 2022 02:13:08 AM CET
Thu 24 Mar 2022 02:13:08 AM CET
2022-03-24 02:13:09 Demonstrating git-hook
```

I have used git version 2.25.1 and ansible version 2.10.17.

Comment: No, because the Ansible module never do `git pull`. It clone the repo or does checkout. An easy confirmation is looking for the word `pull` in the module code: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/git.py

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, there is no `pull` or `merge` happening.
If you want that script to run every time ansible clones/checks out the repository, try the [`post-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) hook.

But as you are already automating it, I would suggest to use ansible to trigger the script instead of a hook.
You could register a variable (e.g. `git_result`) on your `git` module and then decide what to do based on `git_result.changed`.